# What is `sha256` and what should I put as it's value in a `meta.yaml` file of an anaconda package

Tags: python, anaconda, conda-forge

In the `meta.yaml` file of an anaconda package, one of the requirements is the source category, which has `sha256` as a parameter. What is `sha256` and what should I put as it's value. I was originally going to use git, but [conda forge](https://conda-forge.org/) uses tarball or zip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sha256 is a checksum. Checksums are used to verify the integrity of a file — to ensure it has not been altered and that it is actually the file you intend to run.

Checksums are software security mechanisms.

This is a broader topic than Conda, but as discussed below, the command to run in your terminal should look something like:

`curl -sL https://github.com/username/reponame/archive/vX.X.X.tar.gz | openssl sha256`

Comment: So which file should I put as the checksum? And how would I get that checksum?

Comment: I’m honestly not sure. I’ve never distributed a package with conda forge. Have you read this?:   https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/adding_pkgs.html#dev-contribute-pkgs

Comment: Now I see, I guess then you'd use the command `curl -sL https://github.com/username/reponame/archive/vX.X.X.tar.gz | openssl sha256`

Comment: Looks sane to me

Answer (score 2):

As the conda-forge documentation states, which Blake mentioned earlier, you'd use the command `curl -sL https://github.com/username/reponame/archive/vX.X.X.tar.gz | openssl sha256` or get it from PyPI by going to the package description.

Comment: Ideally you would get the sha256 before uploading it somewhere (ie right after you create it). In theory, the file _could_ be manipulated on the server or in transit.